# Regex to catch email addresses in email header

Tags: python, regex, email-headers, email-address

I'm trying to parse a `To` email header with a regex. If there are no `<>` characters then I want the whole string otherwise I want what is inside the `<>` pair.

```python
import re
re_destinatario = re.compile(r'^.*?<?(?P<to>.*)>?')
addresses = [
    'XKYDF/ABC (Caixa Corporativa)',
    'Fulano de Tal | Atlantica Beans <fulano.tal@atlanticabeans.com>'
]
for address in addresses:
    m = re_destinatario.search(address)
    print(m.groups())
    print(m.group('to'))
```

But the regex is wrong:

```
('XKYDF/ABC (Caixa Corporativa)',)
XKYDF/ABC (Caixa Corporativa)
('Fulano de Tal | Atlantica Beans <fulano.tal@atlanticabeans.com>',)
Fulano de Tal | Atlantica Beans <fulano.tal@atlanticabeans.com>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^.*?(?:<(?P<to>.*)>)?$` https://regex101.com/r/e6cz2E/1 Then you can check if there is a group 1 value present, or else print the whole match,.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this regex:

```bash
<?(?P<to>[^<>]+)>?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QvKClJ/1)

**RegEx Demo:**

- `<?`: Match an optional `<`
- `(?P<to>[^<>]+)`: Named capture group `to` to match 1+ of any characters that are not `<` and `>`
- `>?`: Match an optional `>`
- `$`: End

<kbd>[Code Demo](https://tio.run/##VY9BT8MwDIXv@RWWQEoiUDlwQ6VlK9qFCwcOoLEh02YsUhtHjodA4r@XrBtI883vfdZ7jt@ypXA9jn6IxALsFLu3ziXxAQXZE9xmsWhpiL53hnVZm/qxFKqW67J6DasLW9Xn2irsOnYpuZQPlgry6OeHl/vF1WzegGnQfyE0xDkFxX@i1ZcHaLHrMRB0Dp6whx@YSd7FtwhzhyFBuZmAQrC/wz/vfW/tS1VardSGGI7x4AP8N7mZEobpg5OfiuSQ2605knbiziL7IGYoPph2MRl7kE9Uo4W0teP4Cw)</kbd>

**Code:**

```bash
import re
re_destinatario = re.compile(r'<?(?P<to>[^<>]+)>?$')
addresses = [
    'XKYDF/ABC (Caixa Corporativa)',
    'Fulano de Tal | Atlantica Beans <fulano.tal@atlanticabeans.com>'
]
for address in addresses:
    m = re_destinatario.search(address)
    print(m.group('to'))
```

**Output:**

```bash
XKYDF/ABC (Caixa Corporativa)
fulano.tal@atlanticabeans.com
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not make the angle brackets optional, but the whole angle bracket match.

```
^.*?(?:<(?P<to>.*)>)?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `.*?` Match any character, as few as possible
- `(?:` Non capture group to match as a whole part

  - `<(?P<to>.*)>` Match `<`, then capture in named group **to** any character and then match `>` *(note that `.*` can also cross matching `<` and `>`)*
- `)?`  Close the non capture group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e6cz2E/1)

For example:

```
import re

re_destinatario = re.compile(r'^.*?(?:<(?P<to>[^<>\n]*)>)?$')
addresses = [
    'XKYDF/ABC (Caixa Corporativa)',
    'Fulano de Tal | Atlantica Beans <fulano.tal@atlanticabeans.com>'
]

for address in addresses:
    m = re_destinatario.search(address)
    if m:
        if m.group('to'):
            print(m.group('to'))
        else:
            print(m.group())
```

Output:

```
XKYDF/ABC (Caixa Corporativa)
fulano.tal@atlanticabeans.com
```

If you don't want to cross matching the angle brackets or a newline:

```
^.*?(?:<(?P<to>[^<>\n]*)>)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4dve6Z/1)